# Run Workspace One Hub on a Non-Root version of Android VM on Android Phone?

Tags: android-emulator, unrooting, virtualization

I want to run VMWare's Workspace One Hub inside of a virtual machine on my Android (Pixel 5) device.

I have tried Parallel Spaces and VMOS and I can install Hub fine but when I try to set up my account, Hub says the account cannot be set up with a rooted device.

How can I turn off root in my virtual machines so Hub can set up my account fine?

Comment: For an MDM software like Workspace One "root" just means the OS is not genuine (usually tested using Google SafetyNet).

Comment: Any way to trick it with an emulator? Or would my best bet be to remote access a phone?